# Analytics data for 'automated' emails from EXM not displayed/present

Tags: exm

We have configured an EXM automated campaign and the e-mails are being sent as expected. Looking at the dashboards, all percentage numbers are set to 0%.

[image]

How is that possible?
How EXM knows when a link have been opened?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does this happen only for the out-of-the-box email campaigns, or also for your own? If only for the out-of-the-box, can I ask you to try and deactivate and activate them?

Comment: This sounds like a processing error. Check your processing server logs, fix errors, and then rebuild reporting database. That fixed it for us, anyway.

Answer (score 1):

when you check your logfiles you might find something like

```
14052 12:17:31 ERROR Failed to process an email opened task
Exception: Sitecore.EmailCampaign.Model.Web.Exceptions.MessageEventPipelineException
Message: Failed to get campaign for Message id: {guid}, Contact identifier: Alias PII removed
```

This indicates that the campaign can not be found, or that at least it is not available in the "en"-culture.

I had the issue with our emails being created in Dutch (nl-be culture) and translated into French (fr-be culture). EXM created those campaigns only in the nl-be, there was no version for fr-be or en.

**Solutions**

1. Create the en-version of the associated campaign manually.
2. Another option is to fix the Sitecore.Modules.EmailCampaign.Core.Pipelines.HandleMessageEventBase.IdentifyCampaign  processor.

Comment: Hi Bart. The exception is: 2088 17:24:17 ERROR An error ocurred while fetching Profile Photo to update xdb
Exception: System.ArgumentException
Message: The path is not of a legal form.
Source: mscorlib
   at System.IO.Path.LegacyNormalizePath(String path, Boolean fullCheck, Int32 maxPathLength, Boolean expandShortPaths)
   at System.IO.Path.GetFullPathInternal(String path)
   at System.Net.WebClient.GetUri(String path)
   at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadData(String address)
   at Keystone.Intranet.Profile.IntranetProfileManager.SyncXdbPicture()
Any idea? Thanks.

Comment: Hi Leonardo, I have not encountered this error before, but solving it just might fix your statistics.

Comment: Hi @BartVerdonck, can you share how you fixed the IdentifyCampaign code? I'm running into the same problem.

Comment: I didn't fix it, we used bypass solution 1.

Comment: Would this be the same issue (fix available): https://github.com/SitecoreSupport/Sitecore.Support.232559